# Wrapping controller in anonymous function

Tags: angularjs

whether i do:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

// Create the module and define its dependencies.
var app = angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules 
    'ngAnimate',        // animations
    'ngRoute'           // routing

    // Custom modules 

    // 3rd Party Modules

]);

// Execute bootstrapping code and any dependencies.
app.run(['$log',
    function ($log) {
        $log.log('we are loaded');
    }]);
})();
```

or

```
'use strict';

// Create the module and define its dependencies.
var app = angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules 
    'ngAnimate',        // animations
    'ngRoute'           // routing

    // Custom modules 

    // 3rd Party Modules

]);

// Execute bootstrapping code and any dependencies.
app.run(['$log',
    function ($log) {
        $log.log('we are loaded');
    }]);
```

Both seem to work -- what is the difference?

I would appreciate explanation on what an anonymous function is, when i would use one, and why I see controllers written both ways for AngularJs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Both will work. The reason you'll find a lot of JavaScript code wrapped in an anonymous function is to isolate it from other code on the page.

The following code will declare a variable called `name` on a global scope:

```
var name = "Hello World";
```

By using that code, any other script on the page attempting to use a variable called `name` could potentially get an unexpected value of `"Hello World"` because your script declared it as `"Hello World"`.

By wrapping that code in an anonymous function, you keep the code from conflicting with other variables called `name`:

```
(function() {
    var name = "Hello World";
})();
```

In the example above, `name` is now only available inside of the scope of the anonymous function. It is **not** global, and therefore cannot conflict with other code on the page.

In the second code snippet you provided, `app` would now be a global variable that could potentially be overwritten by someone else declaring a global variable called `app`. By wrapping your Angular module in an anonymous function, you prevent your code from conflicting with other code.

Additionally, other people who may use your code won't have to worry about it changing their global scope.

Comment: Would you say this is really necessary then? I found myself doing this just because JSHint guidelines were setup like this.

Comment: It's not required, your code would work fine without it, but it is a best practice for a good reason. As I outlined in the answer, not wrapping your code in some sort of isolating structure can cause it to interfere with other code on the page. As your project grows, you'll start to have issues. Depending on your experience with JavaScript, you may or may not have already experienced this. I can assure you with a fair level of certainty, though, that you that you will eventually encounter an issue with lack of code isolation. :)

Comment: Although @JesseDunlap really nailed that answer, I'll just add that the code school's "Shaping up with angularJS" course sponsored by Google also recommends your first method. and I quote : "Wrapping your Javascript in a closure is a good habit".

Comment: Great explanation. I was concerned with the wrapping of these functions keeping me from accessing angular variables in one file to the other, but I see that is not a problem. Again stated answer!

Comment: I've recently seen an example in AngularJS where the code is wrapped in an anonymous function with parameters as in:

Comment: Phone went in middle of edit.....

I've recently seen an example in AngularJS where the code is wrapped in an anonymous function with parameters as in:
(function(ng, app){
})(angular, appname);
and the main file was not wrapped in an anonymous function but started
var appname = angular.module((...);

I wonder if someone could comment on that practice.

Comment: @MartinHorton It's a bit hard to tell, but it looks like they may have been doing that as a way to pass around the Angular module instance. You can then use `app` in the context of that function to create controllers, directives, services, etc. This however, [isn't good practice](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#definitions-aka-setters) with Angular, and you should instead access the module instance by repeating `angular.module('your_module_name')`.

Comment: @JesseDunlap Thanks for that link. The angular.module documentation says that it returns a NEW module. I was unaware that you could obtain an existing module by angular.module('modulename');
That removes the need for a global variable at all. I agree with the good practices but most examples I see on the net don't seem to follow them.

Comment: @MartinHorton I agree, that is one of my bigger complaints about Angular. It's hard to find a true standard that everyone follows. The [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) I posted is a pretty common go-to resource.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript's local variable ONLY live in the function scope!

So if you use a IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression), like below:

```
(function () {
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
})();
```

You can't access your module outside of the function:

```
(function () {
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
})();

// will get app is undefined error
app.run(['$log', function ($log) {
    $log.log('we are loaded');
}]);
```

Declare local variable instead of global variable is a good idea. That will let your app variable can't be accessed in the global environment.

If you declare a global variable,
your variable can be used anywhere and maybe conflict with other javascript program.